# Is there an API call to trigger an ACPI power button event on SoftLayer H/W servers?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Since there appears to be no way to do an actual soft reboot on SoftLayer H/W servers, we would like to issue the equivalent of an ipmi "chassis power soft" command (which sends an ACPI power button event, which we can configure to trigger a reboot) via the API. I tried the `https://.../rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/<id>/powerOff` call, but while that appears to trigger an ACPI power button event it then powers off the machine within a few seconds (not even giving the server time to shut down properly). So is there a way to trigger just an ACPI power button event via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To power on/off the servers there are only these methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/powerOff
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/powerOn

those API call will power on/off your server, but they will power on/off your sever at once.

I recomend you to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/rebootSoft that method should work for you, if you are not able to perform a soft rebot even using the Sofltyaer's control portal I recomend you to submit a ticket, because your server could have issues.

Regards

Comment: rebootSoft does not work (always results in a hard reboot), as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240869/reboots-via-api-always-result-in-hard-reboots and the associated ticket. Hence the need for an ACPI power button trigger.

Comment: So apparently the answer is no, and it's not an issue with the servers, but with the API: one cannot trigger anything other than hard power events via the API. Period.